# How can I inject google drive api library into chrome extension?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating a chrome extension which will create a button when a user opens google drive in browser. And on clicking the button it should list all the users who has access the to all my files.

I am able to get the result using a web application but when I use the same thing inside drive it does not work.
The google drive api library does not load.

Can anyone help?